# License status querying from slmgr powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm creating a powershell wrapper script to the windows 7 ESU and I need to set up a registry footprints accordingly.

after slmgr /IPK, this is how my slmgr /DLV looks like below
I was able to get the same as string value through .Stdout from the process.

```
Software licensing service version: 6.1.7601.17514

Name: Windows(R) 7, Client-ESU-Year1 add-on for Enterprise,Professional,EnterpriseN,ProfessionalN,Ultimate
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, VOLUME_MAK channel
Activation ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Application ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Extended PID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Installation ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Processor Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88338
Machine Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88339
Use License URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88341
Product Key Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88340
Partial Product Key: XXXXX
License Status: Unlicensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 1
Trusted time: 2/20/2020 2:36:18 PM
Name: Windows(R) 7, Enterprise edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, VOLUME_MAK channel
Activation ID: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
Application ID: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
Extended PID: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
Installation ID: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
Processor Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88338
Machine Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88339
Use License URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88341
Product Key Certificate URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=88340
Partial Product Key: YYYYY
License Status: Licensed
Remaining Windows rearm count: 1
Trusted time: 2/20/2020 2:36:19 PM
```

I need to filter out both the license status and both the activation ID.

Any help would be much appreciated!! I have been googling around for hours and really couldn't help myself.

Comment: What's the question and what does it have to with powershell?

Comment: okay, withthe help of PSADK command Execute-Process -Path "$envSystem32Directory\cscript.exe" -Parameters "/nologo $envSystem32Directory\slmgr.vbs /DLV" -passthru i'm able to get the above activation status and based on the license activation statuses i need to write few registry values.

Comment: Slmgr only does some WMI calls. If you look in the vbs file you can see which calls are being made. After that you can make the same wmi calls using Powershell (that way you don't have to extract or parse text)

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, in powershell

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct | ? { $_.PartialProductKey -ne $null }
```